@Query not returning all data in Spring boot with Spring data neo4j
I have the query below in a Spring boot application using Spring data neo4j. When I run the query as a standalone cypher query, it returns all the data that I am looking for, however, when I run the same query in the spring boot application, it does not return all the data I need. It just goes about a level or 2 deep.
 MATCH path = (stepNode:StepNode {stepNodeId: "<id_goes_here>"})-[:PARENT*0..]-(descendant)
   WITH collect(path) AS paths, stepNode, collect(distinct descendant) AS descendants
   UNWIND descendants AS d
   OPTIONAL MATCH (d)-[r]->(related)
   RETURN stepNode, paths, collect(distinct r) AS relationships, collect(distinct related) AS relatedNodes;

Is there anything I am missing?
This is the query in the spring boot repository
 @Query("""
        MATCH path = (stepNode:StepNode {stepNodeId: $rootNodeId})-[:PARENT*0..]-(descendant)
        WITH collect(path) AS paths, stepNode, collect(distinct descendant) AS descendants
        UNWIND descendants AS d
        OPTIONAL MATCH (d)-[r]->(related)
        RETURN stepNode, paths, collect(distinct r) AS relationships, collect(distinct related) AS relatedNodes;
     """)
    Optional<StepNode> findTreeByRootNodeId(UUID rootNodeId);

I have also noticed that in my logs, right before my query is executed, spring data neo4j displays some data that matches the element_ids of the data that I am able to retrieve from a related entity. Below is the data that is pulled before my query runs with the query
2024-06-22T13:57:45.591Z DEBUG 752174 --- [Game Engine] [nio-9000-exec-1] org.springframework.data.neo4j.cypher    : Executing:
MATCH (rootNodeIds:`Product`) WHERE elementId(rootNodeIds) IN $rootNodeIds WITH collect(rootNodeIds) AS n OPTIONAL MATCH ()-[relationshipIds]-() WHERE elementId(relationshipIds) IN $relationshipIds WITH n, collect(DISTINCT relationshipIds) AS __sr__ OPTIONAL MATCH (relatedNodeIds) WHERE elementId(relatedNodeIds) IN $relatedNodeIds WITH n, __sr__ AS __sr__, collect(DISTINCT relatedNodeIds) AS __srn__ UNWIND n AS rootNodeIds WITH rootNodeIds AS product, __sr__, __srn__ RETURN product AS __sn__, __sr__, __srn__
2024-06-22T13:57:45.591Z TRACE 752174 --- [Game Engine] [nio-9000-exec-1] org.springframework.data.neo4j.cypher    : with parameters:
:param rootNodeIds => ['4:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:547']
:param relatedNodeIds => ['4:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:551', '4:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:557', '4:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:555', '4:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:553', '4:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:556', '4:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:554', '4:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:552', '4:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:561', '4:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:559', '4:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:556', '4:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:554', '4:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:553', '4:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:557', '4:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:555', '4:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:553', '4:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:556', '4:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:554', '4:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:552', '4:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:551', '4:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:556', '4:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:554', '4:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:552', '4:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:556', '4:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:554', '4:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:551', '4:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:561', '4:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:559']
:param relationshipIds => ['5:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:96', '5:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:291', '5:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:342', '5:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:287', '5:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:275', '5:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:341', '5:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:274', '5:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:345', '5:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:344', '5:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:289', '5:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:343', '5:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:306', '5:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:305', '5:e980bb06-70fe-4527-9e8e-20567526a367:326']
2024-06-22T13:57:45.653Z DEBUG 752174 --- [Game Engine] [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.d.n.c.t.Neo4jTransactionManager      : Initiating transaction commit
2024-06-22T13:57:45.662Z  INFO 752174 --- [Game Engine] [nio-9000-exec-1] c.l.d.g.c.game.TemplateController        : [8A26299413CCEF2FB715D1D610E91EF6] product found, about to check for root node
2024-06-22T13:57:45.662Z DEBUG 752174 --- [Game Engine] [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.d.n.c.t.Neo4jTransactionManager      : Creating new transaction with name [com.lucidarray.d_and_c.game_engine.services.game.StepNodeService.findTreeById]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; 'transactionManager'
2024-06-22T13:57:45.674Z DEBUG 752174 --- [Game Engine] [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.d.n.c.t.Neo4jTransactionManager      : Participating in existing transaction
2024-06-22T13:57:45.674Z DEBUG 752174 --- [Game Engine] [nio-9000-exec-1] org.springframework.data.neo4j.cypher    : Executing:
   MATCH path = (stepNode:StepNode {stepNodeId: "421d419a-05a5-4cd6-81f5-3fe5336eead0"})-[:PARENT*0..]-(descendant)
   WITH collect(path) AS paths, stepNode, collect(distinct descendant) AS descendants
   UNWIND descendants AS d
   OPTIONAL MATCH (d)-[r]->(related)
   RETURN stepNode, paths, collect(distinct r) AS relationships, collect(distinct related) AS relatedNodes;

2024-06-22T13:57:45.675Z TRACE 752174 --- [Game Engine] [nio-9000-exec-1] org.springframework.data.neo4j.cypher    : with parameters:
:param 0 => "421d419a-05a5-4cd6-81f5-3fe5336eead0"
:param rootNodeId => "421d419a-05a5-4cd6-81f5-3fe5336eead0"
2024-06-22T13:57:45.705Z DEBUG 752174 --- [Game Engine] [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.d.n.c.t.Neo4jTransactionManager      : Initiating transaction commit

The data that I get when I run the query directly in cypher (I used the table because it might be easier to compare than the graph)

I am using spring boot 3.2.5 and the spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j compatible with it
PS: I would also like to note that when I do a findById (which should in theory fetch as much as it can), I do not get the full tree either. It was partly why I had to write this query to begin with
Any help would be appreciated

Your @Query completely ignores the $rootNodeId parameter passed to findTreeByRootNodeId().
If $rootNodeId is supposed to be used as the stepNodeId value, try this:
@Query("""
   MATCH path = (stepNode:StepNode {stepNodeId: $rootNodeId})-[:PARENT*0..]-(descendant)
   WITH collect(path) AS paths, stepNode, collect(distinct descendant) AS descendants
   UNWIND descendants AS d
   OPTIONAL MATCH (d)-[r]->(related)
   RETURN stepNode, paths, collect(distinct r) AS relationships, collect(distinct related) AS relatedNodes;
""")
Optional<StepNode> findTreeByRootNodeId(UUID rootNodeId);


That was an oversight when I was posting the question . The query does use the actual $rootNodeId in the application. I hardcoded the id because I was doing some testing and forgot to remove it before posting the question.  That particular id produces the data in the screenshot (i.e with cypher) but doesn't when it ends up being passed to sdn
